# What is wrong with my pattern?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

```
public class FileParser {

private String filename = "mydata.txt";
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D\\D\\d+");
private Scanner reader;

public FileParser() throws FileNotFoundException{
    reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
}

public boolean hasMoreData(){
    return reader.hasNext(pattern);
}

public String[] getNextData(){

    return pattern.split(reader.next(pattern));
}

public void close(){
    reader.close();
}
}
```

So this is my code. I am trying to take out a pattern that consists of 2 letters and a number. Why am I getting nothing/ an empty array from the getNextData() function?

Comment: Can you post you file "mydata.txt" or a fragment?

Comment: What's in `mydata.txt`? Is is accessible? Try replacing it with an absolute path to the file to see if it's a file path issue (don't forget to double your slashes on Windows).

Comment: The file is just in the same place as the src folder. That won't that big a deal right?

Comment: The data pattern looks like AZ123; character, character, integer.

Comment: I should just be using Scanner's next with a delimeter for the bar symbol | , right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner.hasNext(pattern)` searches for the pattern that starts between the delimiter. In your case, the delimiter is a `|`. But Scanner's default delimiter is whitespace. You have to either manually change your delimiter to be a `|` or ignore the delimiter altogether. Here's an example using `Scanner.findWithinHorizon`, which does not care about the delimiter:

```
public class FileParserExample {
    private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{2})(\\d+)");
    private Scanner reader;


    public FileParserExample(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    }

    public boolean hasMoreData() {
        String textFound = reader.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0);
        return textFound != null;
    }

    public String[] getNextData() {
        MatchResult match = reader.match();
        String [] pieces = {match.group(1), // AB
                            match.group(2) }; // 123
        return pieces;
    }

    public void close() {
        reader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filename = "mydata.txt";
        FileParserExample parser = new FileParserExample(filename);

        while (parser.hasMoreData()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parser.getNextData()));
        }

        parser.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: I modified it to account for the characters to be separate, but yes it does. Thank you. Why do you suppose that hasNext() doesn't work in this instance?

Comment: Added an explanation about what hasNext() does.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression:

```
    pattern.split(reader.next(pattern));
```

`reader.next(pattern)` is returning the next occurrence of that pattern, e.g. "AB123".

But `pattern.split` is then splitting that string around the pattern, returning the text on either side of it.  Naturally, there is *no* text on either side, because the separator "AB123" is the whole string.

Do you want to just return the string "AB123" ?  You could probably just return the result of `reader.next` in that case.

Comment: So I just have to split it up myself?

Comment: And I am still getting nothing. It cannot find any data.

Comment: The question is: why are you returning a String array? What are you expecting to be in that string array? Is it supposed to be exactly one element containing the string "AB123"? If so, why not have your method getNextData return a String instead?

Comment: Also: what does the data in mydata.txt look like? Is there any whitespace in mydata.txt?

Comment: I want to have the data divided up. I thought that maybe split would do that for me. I want it split up by the two chars and the int.

Comment: The pattern as stated above looks like 2 chars and an int all as one. Separated by the bar symbol. "|"

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is flawed. I believe you want

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w{2}\\d");
```